# Magnific Popup Text Links

Tags: magnific-popup

My website is a gallery of my paintings and photos, but there are also certain sections that have text. Here's a typical page:

http://davelandweb.com/gallery/

The photos in the text use the Magnific Popup just great; however, any text links I have attempt to go to the Magnific Popup instead of just going to the website/link. Any ideas of how to fix? Thanks!